# bootstrap 4 nav tabs left right external control

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to move from one tab to another tab in NAVABAR using external controls (left right arrows).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">

  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-   arrow-right"></span>
```

In the above code, I want to move from Link1 to Link2 and Link2 to Link3 and so on by pressing Left and Right arrows. Please guide me how to achieve the same.

Comment: the correct convention is using tab-index to move from one HTML DOM element to the next; do you really want a left right arrow clicked while the cursor is anywhere on the page to move o your nav?

Comment: Under each tab, lot of content is there. If  left right arrows are there at the bottom, user can easily move from one tab to other. Otherwise, user has to scroll up and press the next tab.